# How can I debug save in cakephp3?

Tags: database, debugging, cakephp-3.0

I could not save my data in data base. And there is no log from cakephp. I used debug functions but they only returned false or useless results. I started to remove lines from my model files one after one. At last I find the problem in one of my relations.
Is there any better solution to debug save?

Comment: What was the problem preventing your save?

Comment: I have two similar fields in my table. language and language_id fields in users table.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487625/save-method-dont-work-when-i-have-both-x-and-x-id-fields-in-my-table-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

> See DebugKit variable section.

It will show all post variable even validation error of your model objects. But one condition , **you have to avoid redirect method when you to debug of save() data**

Comment: In my case it shows nothing even if I prevent redirect

Comment: @anghazighermezi May be debugkit doesn't have properly installed in your system. I think you need 'debug_kit' connection in your  config/app.php  configuration file.This should  be same of default connection. See [Doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html)