# Save method don't work when I have both x and x_id fields in my table in cakephp 3

Tags: database, cakephp-3.0

I have both `language` and `language_id` fields in my users table. When I want to save my data, save method returns `false`.

```
//Table/UsersTable.php
$this->belongsTo('Languages', [
    'alias' => 'Languages',
    'foreignKey' => 'language_id'
]);
```

When I remove this code or remove language field from database, save method works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, remember that CakePHP reserves the a property name where it will store the association data for each of your associations. In Your case, for the `Languages` association it will use the `language` property. If you already have a field with the same name, You can configure your association to use another property name:

```
$this->belongsTo('Languages', [
    'alias' => 'Languages',
    'foreignKey' => 'language_id',
    'propertyName' => 'preferred_language'
]);
```

Personally, I would stick to conventions and not have a `language` field in the database, it make very little sense when you already have a `language_id` field.